# Woocommerce shop page product description

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I added the following code to my functions.php file to add a short product description under the thumbnails on my shop page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 35, 2);
if (!function_exists('lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt'))
{
function lk_woocommerce_product_excerpt()
{
$content_length = 5;
global $post;
$content = $post->post_excerpt;
$wordarray = explode(' ', $content, $content_length + 1);
if(count($wordarray) > $content_length) :
array_pop($wordarray);
array_push($wordarray, '...');
$content = implode(' ', $wordarray);
$content = force_balance_tags($content);
endif;
echo "<span class='excerpt'><p>$content</p></span>";
}
}
```

I do not want that text linked to my title, and would like to be able to align the text left, and change the color. Right now it takes on the same css as the product title. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could also attach the class to p, rather than a span.

Comment: @Sam how would I do that? I copied this code from elsewhere, thanks!

Comment: change `<span class='excerpt'><p>$content</p></span>` to `<p class='excerpt'>$content</p>`

Comment: Thanks @Sam! Do you know how I could change my content length from using words to characters?

Comment: You need to get the content string and then return part of the string.  This should do the trick: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/limit-excerpt-length-by-characters

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
.excerpt{
text-align:left;
color:#fff;
font-size:10px;
font-family:verdana;
font-weight:normal;
}
```